# Google play services freezes Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services

I have two problems with eclipse. I want to add advertisements to my Android Project. I am creating new Android Application Project with the following settings:

- Minimum required SDK: API 13
- Target SDK: API 19
- Compile with: API 22

My first problem with Eclipse is the Java problem as shown below:

> The type ActionBarActivity is deprecated MainActivity.java /hjjhg/src/com/example/hjjhg   line 3

My main problem is when I add Google play services
`sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib` and run the application. Eclipse is working in no-load operation. After a while, Eclipse gives error:

> GC overhead limit exceeded

What is my wrong?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your question to try to make it more clear by adding Blockquotes to your error messages and a unordered list of the project settings.  Please insure that this edit makes sense to you so that someone with a better knowledge of Android can help you out.  I have also re-tagged it with more relevant tags.

Comment: Have you ever using Adnroid Studio? This is the official IDE which sould not crash :D
You can find it here: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Hi Confile, Thanks for your editing. I haven't used Android Studio. I can try but it will take a while hence i'm new in A.Studio.